# Launching a JBoss AS Cluster on Separate Machines to run EJBCA

Tags: java, jboss, cluster-computing, jboss6.x

Right now I am running my EJBCA project on single Jboss server using following command

```
run.sh -c default -b test.mywebsite.net
```

and it works fine, but now I want to launch my EJBCA application on clustered jboss machines
for this I have read following links

***[1.1.2. Launching a JBoss AS Cluster](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html-single/#clustering-quickstart-launching)***

***[1.1.3. Web Application Clustering Quick Start](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html-single/#clustering-quickstart-http)***

then further I read that There are two aspects to setting up web tier clustering:

1. *Configuring an External Load Balancer.*
2. *Configuring Your Web Application for Clustering.*

now my questions are

1. When I go with the External Load Balancer. and when I go with second
   option
2. If I go with second option how it will work ? and what will be my -b
   option while running this Jboss servers.
   because in point ***1.1.2*** I read that

***Two processes can't bind sockets to the same address and port, so we'll have to tell JBoss to use different ports for the two instances.***

**EJBCA Version** :- ejbca_4_0_12

**JBOSS Version** :- jboss-6.1.0.Final

***EDIT 1***

right now I am running my server like this

```
/run.sh -c default -b test.mysite.net
```

so it will listen on

```
https://test.mysite.net:8443/ejbca/
```

now I have to run my application as

***Machine 1***

```
./run.sh -c node1 -g DocsPartition -u 239.255.100.100 \
    -b test.mysite.net -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 \
    -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default
```

***Machine 2***

```
./run.sh -c node2 -g DocsPartition -u 239.255.100.100 \
    -b test.mysite.net -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2 \
    -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default
```

so that I can only access to

```
https://test.mysite.net:8443/ejbca/
```

Please can any one explain this In brife so That I can clear with this things Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

When you follow the documentation you mentioned (Scenario 3: Two Nodes on a Single, Non-Multihomed, Server) you have two JBoss instances:

```
./run.sh -c node1 -g DocsPartition -u 239.255.100.100 \
    -b 192.168.0.101 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 \
    -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default

./run.sh -c node2 -g DocsPartition -u 239.255.100.100 \
    -b 192.168.0.101 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2 \
    -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

They will listen on:

```
1) http://192.168.0.101:8080
2) http://192.168.0.101:8180
```

So to which node you will point your browser to reach the cluster? You can't use either of the two if you want failover. You need to configure a load-balancer.

Furthermore JBoss needs to know that it should replicate the http-session. Therefore you need to configure your web application for clustering. Hence you need to configure 1) and 2) not 1) or 2).

The -b x.x.x.x points to a (the) public IP-address of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so you mean that I have to use External Load Balancer to run my application.

Comment: Yes, you need a load-balancer like mod_cluster or mod_jk. The -b is the IP-Address of machine1 or machine2, I never tried the name, maybe -b machine1.mysite.net and -b machine2.mysite.net works as well.